# How do I setup an AutoResolve Integrated Runtime in Azure Purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I am trying to test out Azure Purview and connect it to an Azure SQL Server. Since the SQL server is hosted in the cloud I want to use the default AutoResolve Integrated Runtime to get connected but there is not one setup or an option to setup a new one. Has anyone else using Purview been able to setup (or needed to setup) an AutoResolve IR?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To connect to Azure SQL DB/MI you can directly go to the Azure Purview portal and register new data sources and select Azure SQL DB/MI.

In this article - [Manage data sources in Azure Purview (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-data-sources), you learn how to register new data sources, manage collections of data sources, and view sources in Azure Purview (Preview).

- Only to connect **on-premise SQL server** you need to Set up a
  **self-hosted integration runtime** to scan the data source.
- If the data source is located on **Azure**, you don't need any integration runtime to scan the data source.

**Reference:** [Register and scan an Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-sql-database).

Answer (score 0):

CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT is absolutely correct, to go a step further, since you know what an auto resolve integration runtime is, you probably are utilizing Azure Data Factory so in addition to registering your SQL Server, you can also link your Azure Data Factory for data lineage purposes. Based on the pipelines that are executed, it will autonomously create the data lineage.

[Navigation to Link Data Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1MkM.png)

[Data lineage created by linking Data Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlU60.png)

Keep in mind, you will have to execute pipelines after linkage for it to pick up the data lineage. Also, for sources or destinations not supported yet, it will not get the data lineage.